# White Patchiness on Plaster over Rock Lathe Rolls

Tags: plaster, radiator, lathe

[image][image]I have a 1950s build house with plaster walls installed over rock lathe (vs. wood lathe). In one room, the walls are showing white patchiness throughout. They feel clammy and have no "slip" to them. In the rest of the house, I can glide my hands across the walls. In this room, there is friction. The problem is happening on both interior and exterior walls. The ceiling does not leak. The crawl space is very large, with a vapor barrier in place, and the area under the room is dry. The heat source for this room is cast-iron baseboard radiators. During the winter, this room is kept about 60-65 degrees.

Comment: I am not sure how to add photos to this post to show the issue. I think it may be efflorescence but I don't know how to properly diagnose or remedy this.

Comment: Look under the question for the "edit" link, lower left. [Edit] the post and use the "sun and mountains" icon above it to add pictures. Don't mess with the code that inserts - look at the preview below the edit box to see how it will look.

Comment: It sounds like efflorescence.